# Using comma(,) when listing several objects

Tags: punctuation, commas

Which is correct expression using comma or not in front of last object when listing several objects?

- ... *A, B, C and D.*
- ... *A, B, C, and D.*

Comment: Hello Kim. This is the Oxford comma.  You might be able to find more details if you search online for that, or see the similar question.  (short answer is "it's your choice")

Answer (score 0):

Both are used. The general usage is without a comma, but there's also something called an Oxford comma.

In sentences like: 'I invited Olivia, Marsha and Maddy', it's difficult to understand whether you're telling Marsha and Maddy that you invited Olivia, or you're stating that you invited all three of them. If you put the comma in, it will be clearer.

So I would suggest 'I invited Olivia, Marsha, and Maddy.' If you're saying you invited all three of them, which you're doing in this case.

For more on Oxford comma, visit [Strategies that pay](https://www.strategiesthatpay.com/oxford-commas/)